# How to print the contents of an OSX textclipping file from terminal?

Tags: macos, bash

In OSX (I'm on 10.7.x, Lion), you can grab some text from most any app and drag it to the desktop to get a "snippet.textClipping" file.  The file is not just raw text, though -- the text is hidden away, somewhere (in a resource?)  I've tried poking around with DeRez, but haven't been able to bend it to my will.  What I'm looking for is the ability to get what one might think would be the output from

`cat mysnippet.textClipping`

**NOTE:** These clippings were made under an older version of OSX.  Maybe Leopard.  Maybe older, it's been a while.  :)

Thanks!

P.S. I've got a folder with 1600+ of them, that's why I'm looking to script this, not just manually copy/pasting them into a text file.

P.P.S.  Yes, if I just select-all then drag into an open, empty text document, it does as you'd expect.  But I still want to do it via script, so I can put the name of the clipping first and a blank line ahead of each, etc.

Comment: Another option, besides DeRez, is to use AppleScript (or Automator, or Python+ScriptingBridge, or whatever you prefer) to script TextEdit to do what you want. That will automatically handle cases like converting the best option of RTFD, RTF, HTML, or plain text to RTFD, getting the charset right, etc.

Comment: You can use `strings < filename.textClipping/rsrc` or just `cat filename.textClipping/rsrc` to get the file contents, but I'm not sure how you'd go about cleaning it up from there. Perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: `filename.textClipping/rsrc: Not a directory.`  The DeRez command in the accepted answer did the trick.  Not a directory may have to do with the age of the clippings -- I don't really know if the formats changed.  (That makes sense though, as many suggestions here and elsewhere on the web that others said work did not work for me.)

Comment: I do like the idea of using AppleScript, as I think it is probably the best way to do this. I just can't write AppleScript code to save my life.

Comment: A late comment on the above `rsrc` access, but it might be useful to someone coming here from Google like me. The right command would be `strings filename.textClipping/..namedfork/rsrc`. It would reveal rtf formatted data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's something ugly that could work:

```
DeRez -only TEXT foo.textClipping | perl -ne 'm|/\* (.*) \*/| && print $1; END {print "\n"}'
```

Basically, it extracts the text from the C-style comments in the `DeRez` output and prints it all on one line. I got the idea from another Stack Overflow question (which I cannot find now).

Comment: +1. But you probably want the utf8, not the TEXT, because otherwise you have to pass it through iconv or something to convert from MacRoman. (And that's assuming you want the plain text, not the RTF or HTML…)

Comment: Oddly, utf8 and UTF8 both returned nothing, but TEXT did what I want (modulo the transition.)  Could be because of the age of the clippings.  Either way, I'm going to take this answer as exactly doing what I want -- thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work correctly with nonprintable and control characters, which get shown as `.` by DeRez.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, chepner's answer didn't do the trick because nonprintable and control characters are crucial to me, and neither did reading `rsrc` because the output was too challenging to clean. Equally unfortunate is that I have a bunch of important text stuck in .textClippings. ‍♂️

Inspired by chepner's solution, this ended up doing the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input="${1:?missing argument}"
derezed="$(DeRez -only utf8 "$input")"
n_lines="$(wc -l <<<"$derezed")"

tail -n $((n_lines-1)) <<<"$derezed" \
    | head -n $((n_lines-2)) \
    | cut -d \" -f 2 \
    | xxd -p -r
```

The script takes the hexadecimal UTF-8 output from `DeRez` and passes it through `xxd`. In my case, the script's output is plain text without any style tags. `file` identifies the output as `Unicode text, UTF-8 text`.

I ran the script on macOS 12.6.7.

Comment: The `wc` and `head` + `tail` combo could be reduced; the entire script then becomes a one-liner `DeRez -only utf8 "${1?Missing argument}" | sed -e '1d' -e '$d' | cut -d \" -f 2 | xxd -p -r` which should be a fair bit more efficient, too. (The last mile optimization woud fold the `cut` into the `sed` script, too - `-e 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/'` - but this hampers legibility a bit, especially if you aren't very good with regex.)